# Shall I get count of records for each categories by using Count(*) or using separate count table? Or any other?

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I am developing a website by using ASP.net and my DB is MYSQL.

Users can put ads for each categories. And I want to display how much ads for each category infront of the category.
Like this.

[image]

To achieve this now I am using a code similar to this

```
SELECT b.name, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM `vehicle_cat` a
    INNER JOIN `vehicle_type` b
    ON a.`type_id_ref` = b.`vehicle_type_id`
GROUP BY b.name
```

This is my explain result

[image]

So assume I have 200,000 records for each category. 
So am I doing the right thing by considering the performance and efficiency?

What if I manage a separate table for store count for each category? If user save a record for each category I am incrementing the value for corresponding type. Assume 100,000 of users will Post records at once. Is it crash my DB?

Or is there any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Start by developing the application using the query.  If performance is a problem, then create indexes on the query to optimize the query.  If indexes are not sufficient, then think about partitioning.

Things not to do:

- Don't create a separate table for each category.
- Don't focus on performance before you have a performance problem.  Do reasonable things, but get the functionality to work first.

If you do need to maintain counts in a separate table for performance reasons, you will probably have to maintain them using triggers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any caching solution, probably in memory caching like **Redis** or **Memcached**. And store your counters here. On cache initialization get them with your SQL script, later change this counters when adding or deleting ads. It will be faster then store them in SQL.

But you probably need to check if COUNT(*) is really hard operation in your SQL database. SQL engine is clever and may be this SELECT is working fast enough or you can optimize it well. If it works, you'd better do nothing until you have perfomance problems!